# Intellij Java/Scala: Delete to delimiter? (like Emacs Paredit)

Tags: java, scala, emacs, intellij-idea, paredit

One of the awesome features of Emacs "paredit" mode that works with Lisp-like as well as other languages like Java/Scala is the ability to just hit Ctrl-k (kill), and it will smartly delete text until the appropriate delimiter, which could be a closing quote-mark, or a closing brace/paren/square-bracket. It will essentially delete things while still keeping your code syntactically valid, i.e. it will delete exactly the right number of closing parens/braces, etc.

Is there such an action or keyboard shortcut in Intellij IDEA? Or how would I define a macro to do this?

Comment: I don't know such feature in IDEA, but you can press CMD+W (in an editor) to select i.e. a word. Keep pressing further to increase this scope. Then delete.

Comment: Yes I know about that (it's either Cmd+W or Alt-UpArray), it keeps expanding the selection. This would allow me to delete the entire current-level block or code or string. However I want to be able to kill the line to the end of the current-level delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that almost works: Record a macro sequence (Mac key-bindings):

1. Expand Selection (Alt Up)
2. Expand Selection (Alt Up)
3. Right with selection (Shift RightArrow)
4. Cut Selection (Cmd X)

Then I bind this macro to Ctrl-K. It works great, e.g. (the vertical bar is the caret position when this is invoked):

`List( "first", "second", "third |string",  "fourth")   => List( "first", "second", "third ", "fourth")

{100, 200, {300|, 400, 500}, 20}   => {100, 200, {300}, 20}`

The case which doesn't quite work exactly the way I want is when I use parentheses:

`(1, 2, (3, |4, 5), 6, 7, 8)    => (1, 2, (3, , 6, 7, 8)`

Notice that it deletes the enclosing right-parenthesis, which is because Expand-Selection includes the enclosing parentheses. If the enclosing expression is a string or has braces, then Expand-Selection does not include the right-hand-side quotes or brace.

If I knew how to do Expand-Selection without including the enclosing parentheses, then this would be perfect, but I can live with what I have now.